# calling Json data returns undefined "

Tags: jquery, json, return-value

When I call json object from php file  it returns undefined. I can see all data writing `alert(data)` but when I write  alert(data.books) it returns undifined.

```
$JSON = '

{
  "books": {
 "book1": "firstbook",
 "book2": "secondbook"
  }
  }
';
```

and I call it with jquery

```
jQuery('#login').live('submit',function(event) {


$.ajax({
    url: 'lib/login.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: $('#login').serialize(),
  success: function(data ) {

alert(' ' +data.books);

  if(data.books.book1){  
alert("OK"); 
}else
{
alert("error");   
}
}

 });

   return false;


});
```

**EDIT**
 This is how it returns alert(data)

```
    {

  "books": {

  "book1": "firstbook",

  "book2": "secondbook"

}

}
```

Comment: Don't you mean `data.books.book1`?

Comment: you are alerting `data.success`, not `data`.

Comment: data.success, isn't defined according to your JSON format reply.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on jQuery 1.4+, the JSON you're returning isn't valid, it needs a set of quotes around the first `books` entry, like this:

```
{
  "books": {
    "book1": "firstbook",
    "book2": "secondbook"
  }
}
```

Earlier versions are more lenient about this, but once you correct it, `alert(data.books)` should result in an object alert.  For your `if()`, you'd use `data.books.book1` to get the entry in the JSON as it is now.

Comment: I changed it like you sad with  "books" but it also says that it is undifined.Also data.books.book1 returns undifined

Comment: @Meko - If you do `console.log(data)`, what are you seeing in the console? It sounds like your reply isn't formatted *exactly* like it is in the question.

Comment: @Meko - You're getting that exact *string* when you alert?

Comment: @Meko - Can you link to an example page? It's as if `dataType: 'json'` isn't even there, as it's seeing it as a string.  Without headers saying it's JSON or the `dataType`, it'll be a normal string...that seems to be what's happening.

Comment: I imported in index.html page where my form , <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script> for jquery. Should I use for Json too?

Comment: @Meko - I meant a URL of a page demonstrating the problem above :)  The JSON page should have *nothing* but the JSON in it coming back.

Comment: site is on my local comp. not on internet.

Comment: @Meko - What does your output look like now?

Comment: if I write alert(data) it shows  [object Object]  if I write alert(data.book1) it shows firstbook

Answer (score 0):

I changed in .php file  like

```
$arr = array ( "book1" => "firstbook" ,"book2" => "secondbook" );
```

now it shows when i write  alert(data.book1)   out put  fisrtbook .for checking if(data.book1) it works.